# How to upload image from website to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, html

**Help me pls!! I can't upload image file to firebase storage.**

> have any update for this code?

*Sign.php:217 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined at HTMLInputElement. (Sign.php:217)*

on Sign.php:217 it's this code : var storageRef=firebase.storage().ref("Picture/"+file.name);
but I don't know how to fix it

```js
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js";
  import { getStorage } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-storage.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDAmerIVJpJVQMbpX1aTPHTkKuT1ULM_Gw",
    authDomain: "aboutinkjet-e6e0c.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "aboutinkjet-e6e0c",
    storageBucket: "aboutinkjet-e6e0c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "7922742945",
    appId: "1:7922742945:web:124d23113a55778727e2e0",
    measurementId: "G-4SETNPDNPB"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const storage = getStorage(app);

  var uploader=document.getElementById("uploader");
  var fileButton = document.getElementById("inpFile");
  fileButton.addEventListener('change',function(e){
      var file=e.target.files[0];
      var storageRef=firebase.storage().ref("Picture/"+file.name);
      var task=storageRef.put(file);
      task.on('state_changed',function progress(snapshot){
        var percentage=(snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
        uploader.value=percentage;
      },function error(err){
          console.log(err.message);
     },function complete(){
         console.log("Upload Complete!!!");
     });   
  });
</script>

<script>
        const inpFile = document.getElementById("inpFile");
        const previewContainer = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
        const previewImage = previewContainer .querySelector(".image-preview__image");
        const previewDefaultText = previewContainer .querySelector(".image-preview__default-text");
        
        inpFile.addEventListener("change", function(){
            const file = this.files[0];
            
            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();

                previewDefaultText.style.display = "none";
                previewImage.style.display = "block";

                reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
                    console.log(this);
                    previewImage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
                });

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```css
.image-preview{
            width: 50%;
            min-height: 100px;
            border: 2px solid #dddddd;
            margin-top : 15px;
            /*Default text*/
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #cccccc;
            margin-left: 15%;
        }
        .image-preview__image{
            display:none;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #uploader{
            margin-left:15%;
        }
```

```html
<label for="file">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg" name="pic" id="inpFile" />
<div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
  <img src="" alt="Image Preview" class="image-preview__image">
  <span class="image-preview__default-text">Image Preview</span>
</div>

<progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you should write `import firebase` in your main file, like

```js
import firebase, { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.1/firebase-app.js";
```